# Last element is hidden behind BottomAppBar with ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using a ReorderableListView builder in combination with a Bottom App Bar with a FAB.
I set extendBody because I want the FAB notch to be transparent when scrolling up/down the list. However with a ReorderableListView I cannot scroll down to the last list item because the list item is hidden behind the Bottom App Bar.

Here's a demonstration:

[image]

This is not the case with a regular ListView as you can see in the code example below and on this picture right here. This would be my intended behaviour because the last list item is fully visible:

[image]

Important: It's not a solution to just set extendBody to false because there would be no transparent notch when scrolling. The scrolling behaviour itself is correct for ReorderableListView and ListView and looks like this when scrolling:

[image]

Is there a way to access the last list element with a Reorderable List View similar than with a List View?

Here's a code example with both versions:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(SO());
}

class SO extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> myList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
            builder: (context) => Scaffold(
              extendBody: true,
              appBar: AppBar(),
              body:
              // CANNOT scroll up to the last element
              ReorderableListView.builder(
                  itemCount: myList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      key: ValueKey(myList[index]),
                      height: 150,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${myList[index]}')),
                    );
                  },
                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex){
                  if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex --;
                  final item = myList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  myList.insert(newIndex, item);
              },
              ),

              /*
              // CAN scroll up to the last element
              ListView.builder(itemCount: myList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    key: ValueKey(myList[index]),
                    height: 150,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${myList[index]}')),
                  );
                },
              ),
              */
              floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                notchMargin: 18,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                ),
              ),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `padding` like this:

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight + 16),//<--- add this
        itemCount: myList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            key: ValueKey(myList[index]),
            height: 150,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${myList[index]}')),
          );
        },
        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
          if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex--;
          final item = myList.removeAt(oldIndex);
          myList.insert(newIndex, item);
        },
      ),
```

Comment: @BugsBuggy didn't this fix your issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a nice workaround. Is there a more dynamic way of getting the height of the Bottom App Bar?

Comment: the default value is 56, but I see in your code you set your bottom bar hight to 60.

Comment: You're right, in this case it's hard coded in this simple demo. But can we get the value dynamically of the Bottom App Bar?

Comment: you can use `kBottomNavigationBarHeight` .

Comment: Missed it from the other answers, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a bottom edge inset. An inset would add padding inside the control without losing your transparent notch behaviour.

This can be done with something like -

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
  padding(EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0)),
  ...
)
```

This is based on the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/padding.html) though I think it is a weird parameter naming as padding suggests `offet` but documentation says this as inset. Hence I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add **dynamic padding** to the ReorderableListview as below

```
ReorderableListView.builder(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: kBottomNavigationBarHeight + 15.0), // add this
                  itemCount: myList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      key: ValueKey(myList[index]),
                      height: 150,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${myList[index]}')),
                    );
                  },
                onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex){
                  if (newIndex > oldIndex) newIndex --;
                  final item = myList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                  myList.insert(newIndex, item);
              },
              ),
```

> kBottomNavigationBarHeight

get the height of bottom navigation bar and add as padding..